SSE not working only over HTTPS, need a solution that doesn't change Nginx
HTTP, testing locally works perfectly. As soon as I deploy it to our test server, it doesn't detect any clients from the front-end anymore. When I call the function to send the data through SSE from the server, the clients connected to the server are always 0.
I have researched and found other people have solved this by adding "X-Accel-Buffering: no" header. I added this but still, no luck.
Another solution is changing Nginx config to disable proxy buffering, but since I'm not too well-versed on the server side of things so I'm not sure if adding this config will mess anything else up.
Is there any other possible solution without having to change the config?
Here's my back-end:
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Picker } from 'meteor/meteorhacks:picker';

const clients = {};

Picker.route('/api/v1/sse/:clientToken', (params, req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const clientToken = params.clientToken;

    if (!clientToken) {
      res.writeHead(400);
      res.end('Partner token is required');
      return;
    }

    // set headers
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-transform');
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no'); 

    res.flushHeaders();

    // add client once connected
    if (!clients[clientToken]) {
      clients[clientToken] = [];
    }
    clients[clientToken].push(res);

    // on disconnect, remove clients
    req.on('close', () => {
      try {
        clients[clientToken] = clients[clientToken].filter(client => client !== res);
        if (clients[clientToken].length === 0) {
          delete clients[clientToken];
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error during client disconnect handling:", err);
      }
    });

    // send a heartbeat message every 15 seconds
    const heartbeatInterval = setInterval(() => {
      res.write(': heartbeat\n\n');
    }, 15000);

    req.on('close', () => {
      clearInterval(heartbeatInterval);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error in SSE route:", err);
    res.writeHead(500);
    res.end('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

export const sendEventToClients = (clientToken, data) => {
  try {
    const tokenClients = clients[clientToken];
    if (tokenClients) {
      // send data to client connected by same token
      tokenClients.forEach(client => {
        try {
          client.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`);
          client.flush()
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Error sending data to client:", err);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log(`No clients found for clientToken: ${clientToken}`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error in sendEventToClients function:", err);
  }
};

Meteor.methods({
  triggerSSEEvent(clientToken, data) {
    sendEventToClients(clientToken, data);
  }
});

And my front-end implementation:
 useEffect(() => {
    const callSse = async () => {
      const clientToken = await getData('authToken')

      const eventSource = new EventSource(`${apiUrl}/sse/${clientToken}`)

      eventSource.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        try {
          const operation = JSON.parse(event.data)
          setBookingOperations(operation)
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error parsing SSE event data:', error)
        }
      })

      eventSource.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
        console.error('EventSource failed:', error)
        eventSource.close()
      })

      return () => {
        eventSource.close()
      }
    }

    callSse()
  }, [])


Since you use picker I assume you are using a Meteor 2.x release that uses connect under the hood as http middleware stack. Maybe you do a proof of concept with a clean Meteor 3.0.1 project (which uses express now as middleware stack)  and look if you can implement the minimal solution from this answer
